# InputText component results in TypeError: e.target is null when typing into text box (PrimeReact library, using arrow function)

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using PrimeReact and I have a datatable of persons:

[image]

When selecting any row, a sub panel is shown having dropdowns, check boxes and text inputs:

[image]

Text input code:

```
<div className="p-col-4">
    <InputText id="first-name"
               value={this.state.selectedEntity.firstName}
               onChange={(e) => this.setState(state => (state.selectedEntity.firstName = e.target.value))} />
</div>
```

I keep the state of the first name on a nested property called `selectedEntity`. That's about the only non-straightforward construct here in the `setState` call. However, this gives me an error in the browser as soon as I type:

[image]

**QUESTION(S)**:

What's wrong?

Is this a bug in PrimeReact?

I'm using PrimeReact 5.0.0-rc2.

---

**EDIT 1:**

BTW the dropdown and check box you see there, they seem to work with an arrow function. Similar code:

Dropdown:

```
<div className="p-col-4">
    <Dropdown optionLabel="name"
              optionValue="gender"
              value={this.state.selectedEntity.gender}
              options={[{"gender": "MALE", "name": "Mr"}, {"gender": "FEMALE", "name": "Mrs"}]}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState(state => (state.selectedEntity.gender = e.value))}
              placeholder="Select a gender" />
</div>
```

Check box:

```
<div className="p-col-4">
    <Checkbox inputId="incognito"
              value="Incognito"
              checked={this.state.selectedEntity.incognito}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState(state => (state.selectedEntity.incognito = e.checked))} />
</div>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I've created a test case here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-test-forked-4blln?file=/src/index.js

Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: Can you share the `InputText` component? (Also, are you ok having these names in the screenshot? Maybe you want to hide the names before sharing on internet?)

Comment: The `InputText` component is from PrimeReact... and yes I will replace the images with fake data.

Comment: Maybe the error occurs on render when the target is not "ready yet". Maybe adding a if (e.target) { } around the `this.setState()` could be a quick fix?

Comment: The arrow function works for the `DropDown` and the `Checkbox` component. See edit.

Comment: You are using an RC version... expect bugs. Does it work if you use a non-RC version?

Comment: Also happens with stable 4.2.2... looks like a bug to me -> https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1600

Comment: @Kawu please self-answer this question with the information that this is a known bug, including that link, to help future people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the `InputText`'s `onChange` event handler to accept an arrow function of the given form, you must also use `e.persist()` prior to `setState( ... )`:

So instead of

```
onChange={(e) =>
   this.setState((state) => (state.selectedEntity.firstName = e.target.value))
}
```

use

```
onChange={(e) => {
   e.persist();
   this.setState((state) => (state.selectedEntity.firstName = e.target.value))
}}
```

Please see

[github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1600](http://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1600)

for the complete discussion.

PS: at the time of this writing, the answer as to why this isn't needed for the `Dropdown` and `Checkbox` components is still pending.